# Re-using IBOutlet programmatically

Tags: objective-c, ios, cocoa, uiview, iboutlet

I have an UIView created in IB with some labels and custom colours and linked that as an IBOutlet so I could have access to it in my viewController.

```
@property (strong, nonatomic) IBOutlet UIView *tile;
```

although I would like to create more of this outlet within a loop:

```
- (void)viewDidLoad {
    [super viewDidLoad];
    int i = 0;
    while (i <= 9) {
        UIView *cTile = [self.tile copy];
        [self.view addSubview:cTile];
        i += 1;
    }
}
```

So I'm trying to copy this `tile` outlet and then add the copied view to the main view.
Apparently this can't be done and returns an error.

Is it possible to achieve such behaviour and re-use/duplicate an IBOutlet?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I dont think what you want to do is possible as UIView doesn't conform to the NSCopying protocol.

Best bet would be to create your "tile" as a UIView subclass or crate a nib for it and then you can reload it as many times as you want.